# Idiomatically moving/sorting values from one Vec into another

Tags: rust, functional-programming

I recently picked up rust, coming from a python background. I'm still getting the hang of functional programming so I'm looking for insight/feedback on writing idiomatic rust.

In the example below I have a list of `Parent` elements and `Child` elements and want to sort the `Child` elements into their respective parents based off of an `id`.

In python I would nest two for loops, perform a test and continue accordingly. But I'm not quite sure if there is a better/performant/idiomatic way of doing this.

I've marked the section of the code in question. Although any feedback is great!

Here's a working playgound:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=233cfa5b5798090fa969ba348a479b1c

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Parent {
    id: String,
    children: Vec<Child>,
}

impl Parent {
    pub fn from_id(id: String) -> Self {
        Self {
            id,
            children: Vec::new(),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Child {
    parent_id: String,
}

impl Child {
    pub fn from_parent_id(parent_id: String) -> Self {
        Self { parent_id }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut parents: Vec<Parent> = vec!["a", "b", "c"]
        .iter()
        .map(|s| s.to_string())
        .map(Parent::from_id)
        .collect();

    let mut children: Vec<Child> = vec!["a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c"]
        .iter()
        .map(|s| s.to_string())
        .map(Child::from_parent_id)
        .collect();

    // Is there a better way to do this?
    while let Some(child) = children.pop() {
        for parent in parents.iter_mut() {
            if child.parent_id == parent.id {
                parent.children.push(child);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    dbg!(parents);
    dbg!(children);
}
```

Comment: Do you _have_ to use `Vec` here? Seems much more natural to treat that whole parent/child relationship as a `HashMap<String, Vec<Child>>` or something. Then you don't have to iterate over the parent vector each time just to find the one with the right id.

Comment: Hmm I think so? I'm querying two different databases and returning two `Vec`s and then shuffling them together based off of an `id`. Also the actual `Parent` and `Child` structs are more complex types with additional fields which are later being serialized with `serde`.

Comment: I guess a solution with fewer side effects would be to just consume `children`, [like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c9d6e3f4855f7c799d8e40c74a40e830), which allows `children` to not be `mut`. Then you could make it [a bit more functional](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=96139bd396cdf1b22205b54ca2a32489) by using `find()` and `map()`. You could convert the outer `for` loop into `children.into_iter().for_each(|child| ...)`, but that doesn't seem to improve readability.

Comment: But instead of trying to make your code perfectly functional, you should consider the time complexity of this operation, which is currently `O(n*m)` - if those numbers can get large, it could blow up. Creating a temporary mapping of id->position for the parents vector can make it `O(n+m)` instead, as [shown here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a828759f483c8c513b18abc028374aa0).

Comment: Oh this is a great point. I see it now. I don't expect the instances of `Parent` to exceed 1000 but the `Child` ones certainly will. I'm not sure how flexible the current implementation of the surrounding code is but the temporary mapping is great idea especially if I cant find a workaround. Lemme see what I can do with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have is okay. But here are some alternative ideas on implementation.

Supporting conversion from one type to another is easy to achieve by implementing `From` as an alternative to the `.from_id()` and `.from_parent_id()` methods.

```rust
impl From<&str> for Parent {
    fn from(id: &str) -> Self {
        Self { id: id.into(), children: vec![] }
    }
}

impl From<&str> for Child {
    fn from(id: &str) -> Self {
        Child { parent_id: id.into() }
    }
}
```

*The subsequent examples assume `From` has been implemented as above.*

Having `From` implemented for the types can simplify creating the objects from the vector of id's. The difference isn't dramatic though. The code you have for creating the `Child` and `Parent` objects is fine too.

```rust
    let mut parents  = vec!["a", "b", "c"]
                        .into_iter().map(|id| id.into())
                        .collect::<Vec<Parent>>();

    let mut children = vec!["a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c"]
                        .into_iter().map(|id| id.into())
                        .collect::<Vec<Child>>();
```

Below, is an example of a more functional way of matching the `Child` objects up with the `Parents` by invoking `.for_each()` - a typical `for` loop would be just as good.

```rust
    children.into_iter().for_each(|child| {
        let cmp = |p: &Parent| p.id.cmp(&child.parent_id);

        if let Ok(idx) = parents.binary_search_by(cmp) {
            parents[idx].children.push(child); 
        }});
```

Binary search in the above example is one way to make the process of matching children to parents more efficient, assuming the `Parent`s are in order by their ID's.

An even more efficient way is to put the parents into a `HashMap`.

```rust
    let mut parents  = vec!["a", "b", "c"]
                        .into_iter().map(|id| (id.into(), id.into()))
                        .collect::<HashMap<String, Parent>>();
```

Below shows matching `Child` objects to `Parents` in the `HashMap` in a way similar to the binary search example.

```rust
    children.into_iter().for_each(|child| { 
        if let Some(p) = parents.get_mut(&child.parent_id) {
            p.children.push(child); 
        }});
```

Comment: Isn't it better to use `children.into_iter()` than `children.drain(0..)`? Draining is for when you need to retain the vector, which doesn't seem to be the case for the OP, who likely used `pop()` because it was a solution that worked.

Comment: @user4815162342, yes. you're right. the `Drain` iterator isn't necessary. I removed it from examples. Thanks.

Comment: This was super helpful! Especially the `From` trait implementation. I ended up reworking things so I could store all the `Parent` objects into a `HashMap`. Also `clippy` suggested I use a `if let` block to push `Child` elements into `Parent.children`. Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome @se432. Yes, I'd expect clippy to suggest the `if let`  and that's probably the better stylistic choice. I used the `match` because it took up less horizontal space for the example. If you wanted something that has features of both a `HashMap` and iterable sorted list to store your parents, you could consider `BTreeMap`.

Comment: @Todd If I'm understanding correctly, `HashMap` _should_ be sufficient in my case. In the actual data, `Parent.id` is a uuid-esque string that holds no order information nor do I ever need to access the data in an ordered fashion. So I'm assuming I'm not going to gain any advantage using `BTreeMap`...?

Comment: Agreed, `HashMap` is what you want. @se432

Answer (score 2):

Popping items off the end of the vector is mostly used when you need to retain parts or all of the vector. If you need to consume the whole vector, you can pass it to the `for` loop directly:

```
for child in children {
    for parent in parents.iter_mut() {
        if child.parent_id == parent.id {
            parent.children.push(child);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use iterators to look for the parent, like this:

```
for child in children {
    parents
        .iter_mut()
        .find(|parent| parent.id == child.parent_id)
        .map(|parent| parent.children.push(child));
}
```

The most important issue with performance is that this needs to perform `n*m` iterations in total, where `n` and `m` are number of parents and children. If those numbers can go into tens of thousands, you will end up with hundreds of millions of iterations, which will slow you down. You can create a temporary mapping of id->position for the parents vector can make the operation `O(n + m)`:

```
let parent_pos_by_id: HashMap<_, _> = parents
    .iter()
    .enumerate()
    .map(|(idx, parent)| (parent.id.clone(), idx))
    .collect();

for child in children {
    if let Some(&parent_pos) = parent_pos_by_id.get(&child.parent_id) {
        parents[parent_pos].children.push(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @user4815162342! I never gave `O(n)` a thought when designing this.